# Expressing through summation subscript

Tags: notation

I am trying to define an equation to model a psychological phenomenon such as e.g.:

$B=\sum_{i=1}^k (P_{ij} T_j)$

Where $B$ is boredom, $j$ is an attribute of a given situation, $i$ is a stimulus in that situation, $P_{ij}$ is the performance perception of that stimulus $i$ over attribute $j$, and $T_j$ is the effect of the time of the day over attribute $j$

My question is, does $T_j$ states what I want to say (i.e., that $j$ is affected by the time of the day)? Or it would be more appropriate to use $T_{ij}$ or other notation instead?

Thanks

Comment: There are several problems here. Firstly, writing $\sum$ with a $j$ in the upper index simply tells you sum the values inside the sum with $i$ running from $1$ to $j$. Thus $j$ it must be a number! Can attributes be numbers in psychology?

Comment: Thanks, and apologies but there was a mistake in the formula. It is fixed now to  $B=\sum_{i=1}^k$. As $k$ is supposed to represent any number of attributes for a given situation.  Hope now is clearer. Does this imply that $j$ is affected by time of the day $T$?